# Display header and footer in controller method

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

In my controller method I am printing one simple message.

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello,, Welcome to IndexController...";
    }
```

But, that message is displaying on a blank page. I want to add header and footer to that page and my message should be displayed in between.

Can anyone help me? Which steps should I follow to achieve this?

Following is the code I have added in local.xml:

```
<emq_mymodule1_index_index> <!-- frontendname_controllername_actionname -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="abc" template="abcd/demo.phtml" />
        </reference>
</emq_mymodule1_index_index>
```

Comment: Please share your config file as well

Comment: I have updated that code.

Comment: Can you please share config.xml code and controller file and name

Comment: @AmitBera  answer given by Adarsh Khatri is working but I followed the same steps on other magento installation and that template file is not appearing i controller method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need few changes:

First change your action as follow: (`function first letter should be small i`)

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('custommodule/blockname') //you need block, define in config.xml
            ->setTemplate('path/to/your/template/file.phtml');
        $this->renderLayout();

        $data = 'my data';
        Mage::register('custom_var', $data);
    }
```

This means, you have file in `path/to/your/template/file.phtml` and have to have any content in that file, which will be displayed as you wanted.

Now you can call registered data as follow:

```
$data = Mage::registry('custom_var');
var_dump($data);
```

in your phtml file.

Comment: I have created one template file and the message from that template file is displaying properly. But how can I pass data from my controller method and then display it in that template? can you help me?

Comment: I have updated, please check.

Comment: I have added 
 $data = 'my data';
Mage::register('custom_var', $data);
in my controller method and
$data = Mage::registry('custom_var'); 
echo $data;
in template file but, that data is not displaying.

Comment: Here in my indexAction(): 

public function indexAction()
 {
  $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        $data = 'my data';
        Mage::register('custom_var', $data);
 }

Comment: Make sure your template is called correctly, you can test it by just typing anything in template file.

Comment: Yes  template is called correctly but,  
$data = Mage::registry('custom_var');
echo $data;
is not printing anything.
echo "Coming from demo.phtml.."; <=== this line is displayed properly.

Comment: Do `var_dump` instead.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use var_dump and where?

Comment: You can call it in phtml file

Comment: Thank you @Adarsh answer given by you is working but I followed the same steps on other installation and that template is not appearing in controller.

Comment: If you have followed same as in working installation, then there shouldn't be any problem. It's hard to tell what's going on from here. Might be xml playing the role.